# Pointer to array when calling from C# to COM

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, interop

I have a given COM function (written in C++), which returns a pointer to BYTE*

**IDL**:

```
HRESULT calculate([in] BSTR request, [out] BYTE* result, [out] LONG* size);
```

**The COM C++ code**:

```
STDMETHODIMP Calc::calculate(BSTR request, BYTE* result, LONG* size)
{
//calc
  int c_size = somesize();
  char* c_result = somearray();

//copy to result
  *size = c_size;
  result = new BYTE[c_size+1];
  memcpy(result, c_result, c_size);
  *(result+c_size) = '\0';

//free and return
  delete[] c_result;
  return S_OK;
}
```

This ends up in .NET/C# interop as

```
calculate(string request, [out] byte result, [out] int size)
```

My questions:

1. what type to pass as 2nd parameter? The C# offered byte? But it is a "pointer to byte" in C++? Is it ok?
2. how to convert the 2nd parameter to byte[] in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Your IDL is invalid, it doesn't return a BYTE*.  This cannot work from C++ either.  The argument type needs to be BYTE**.  As long as you need to fix this, consider using SAFEARRAY instead so the C# interop is simple.

Comment: @Hans Passant: why does it need to be BYTE**? I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking to ask to rewrite to use SAFEARRAY(BYTE).
But how would it work if .....[out] BYTE**.... would be there at 2nd pos?

Comment: Well, your assignment now becomes: *result = new BYTE[..].  So that you'll actually update the caller's pointer.

Comment: @Martze: I think, as you are changing the value of the result as pointing it to a new address.

Comment: @user1525388: thanks, that was obvious :)